# Confuse in database size and getting memory error - wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, out-of-memory

I am facing strange issue. In Cpanel it shows database size : 300 MB , Then I go to database and have ran query to get each table size , now when do SUM of all table sizes it comes to 52 MB only ,so what is issue here?

I am getting frequently below error :

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home2/eps/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1938

I have tried all possible to solve this error but still not success.

Also can anyone please tell me that is Database size == all table size sum of that database ?? or it can be diff.?

Also please give me way to remove above error for permanent

**Our memory plugin showing following status :**

Usage Sample: 39.37MB (15%)

Peak Usage: 39.47MB (15%)

All-Time: 255.94MB on 12/10/14 @ 3:40 pm    (shutdown)

Load Averages: 0.09 0.02 0.01

WP Memory Limit: 256MB

PHP Memory Limit: 256M

**Memory Usage : 85.17 MB avg.**

**Have just run P3 - scan wordpress plugin and got following audit, hope this help supporter to help me :**

[image: Memory Audit]

Comment: Ahme, the error can be with Server RAM? If yes the server RAM is different from database space

Comment: Just because your DB is "X" bytes large, doesn't mean it'll occupy "X" bytes if you `select *` into your client code. Every variable in PHP has metadata associated with it. your 4-byte integer could very well be occupying 32 bytes of ram (whatever PHP's overhead is).

Comment: Oh, duh, @MarcB I wasn't even realizing he was talking more about how much memory the data takes...

Comment: All , Please ask me if you need more detail info...I really need solution.

Comment: [I would start by Googling "wp-db.php line 1938"](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-in-wp-dbphp-1) and a wealth of information will leap forth.

Comment: @sjagr - I already done lot of research but still no solution works for me.

Comment: You failed to list what you've tried in your question though - so I have to assume you've done nothing. There's very little detail to help us help you.

Comment: @sjagr - Yes you are right but I have tried lots of way to solve it so I have not mentioned in question.